# Point of /users/{id}/inbox?

Tags: support, api-v2

What is the need for the user ID in:
https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/user-inbox

Given that it will only return the inbox of the authenticated user, and deny a mismatching user id.

The only needed route is the Network /users route ( https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/inbox) surely? As the inbox is a Network feature anyway, the site supplied is irrelevant (well judging by the docs and that both routes return the same content?)

Answer (score 1):

The inbox methods have a number of aliases to aid in their consumption.

`/me/inbox` is provided for those apps that are single site focused.
`/users/{ids}/inbox` is provided for symmetry with every other `/me` method.  It is also not inconceivable that `access_token`s that can access multiple users will be possible, although there is no way to create them at this time.

Strictly, yeah, you can do all this with just the `/inbox` method.

Technically `/posts/{ids}/comments` is covered completely by `/questions/{ids}/comments` and `/answers/{ids}/comments` but it makes some use cases easier, so we supply it.

Same logic really.

Comment: Ok thanks, I was just wondering if I was missing something, btw there doesn't seem to be vectorised inbox method  according to the docs?

Comment: @Jonathan - on the balance I thought it more confusing to call those methods vectorized in the docs while "one user -> one access_token" holds true.  Didn't want people trying to pass multiple access_tokens, or the like either.